# Boolean operators within apply function giving wrong output

Tags: r, boolean, apply

I am trying to iterate through a data frame using the apply function and output TRUE if both columns in the data frame are greater or equal to 9. My code is below to show how I am trying to do this, along with an example output. However, when I look at the output, all of the output values are FALSE, even when they should be TRUE.

```
#Function to remove any proteins that have a certain number of NA values
RemoveNA <- function(input){
    file <- read.table(input, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    numrows <- nrow(file)
    #Set groups
    Adj <- file[,3:12]
    Non <- file[,13:22]
    #Count the number of values that are not NA in each group
    AdjSum <- rowSums(!is.na(Adj))
    NonSum <- rowSums(!is.na(Non))
    combined <- data.frame(AdjSum, NonSum)
    d <- apply(combined, 1, function(x) x[1] >= 9 & x[2] >= 9)
    d2<-is.data.frame(d)
    newcombined <- data.frame(AdjSum, NonSum, d2)
    print(head(newcombined))
}
```

Output:

```
      AdjSum NonSum    d2
   1     10     10 FALSE
   2     10     10 FALSE
   3     10     10 FALSE
   4      0      1 FALSE
   5      1      1 FALSE
   6      0      1 FALSE
```

Is there anything that appears wrong with this code?

The ultimate goal of this code really is to take a file and determine which rows to keep based on how many NA values are present.

Thank you for your help,
Allison G.

Comment: `d2<-is.data.frame(d)` returns `FALSE` because `apply` returns a matrix (or array). You probably meant `d2 <- as.data.frame(d)`.

Comment: You might also want to look into `na.omit`

Comment: Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or

```
 dat$d2 <- rowSums(dat>9)==ncol(dat)
```

#### data

```
 dat <- structure(list(AdjSum = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 0L), NonSum = c(10L, 
 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("AdjSum", "NonSum"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```